# PHP: curly braces variable $fin_type_{$z} not working

Tags: php

I have this:

```
echo 'm=>'.$fin_type_2; // echoes 'test text';
```

Now, if I do the following, I get nothing, whereas I was expecting the same result as above. What I am doing wrong here ?

```
$z=2;
echo 'm=>'.$fin_type_{$z}; // echoes nothing but m=>
```

Help appreciated. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would use something like this:

> ${'fin_type_'.$z}

(besides [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) of php documentation helped myself sometimes)

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use [arrays](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php) (numeric and associative) to achieve your goal.

Comment: +1. the other answers solve the problem asked, but variable variable names are generally a bad idea; not quite as bad as `eval()`, but a close second. This definitely looks like a case where arrays would be a much simpler and saner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that closest you can get is

```
<?php
$fin_type_2 = 'test text';
$z = 2;
$v = "fin_type_$z";
echo 'm=>'.$v;
```

However, think twice before applying variable variables like that. Perhaps using array would fit your case better?

```
<?php
$fin_type = array();
$fin_type[2] = 'test text';

$z = 2;
echo "m=>{$fin_type[$z]}";
```

Comment: thanks Mchl. I will think about array next time. I was till now working with $i values coming through a while loop.